# Cannot assign value of type '()' to type '[customObject]' - while in a completion handler

Tags: ios, json, swift, object

I'm trying to reload a collection view after the json data has been updated but am running into the error:

> Cannot assign value of type '()' to type '[ChannelInfo]'

This is how I have the custom object 'ChannelInfo' setup:

```
class ChannelInfo: NSObject {

  var logo: String?
  var channelName: String?
  var id: NSNumber?


  init(logo: String, channelName: String , id: NSNumber) {

    self.logo = logo
    self.channelName = channelName
    self.id = id
  }

  init(resDictionary: [String:Any]) {

    logo = resDictionary["artwork_608x342"] as? String
    channelName = resDictionary["name"] as? String
    id = resDictionary["id"] as? NSNumber

  }


  static func updateAllChannels(completionHandler:@escaping (_ channels: [ChannelInfo]) -> Void){

    let nm = NetworkManager.sharedManager// singleton handles network connections and json parsing


    nm.getJSONData(urlExtension: "channels/all/0/50", completion: {
      data in

      var channels = [ChannelInfo]()

      if let jsonDictionary = nm.parseJSONFromData(data)
      {
        let resultsDictionaries = jsonDictionary["results"] as! [[String : Any]]
        for resultsDictionary in resultsDictionaries {// enumerate through dictionary
          let newChannel = ChannelInfo(resDictionary: resultsDictionary)
          channels.append(newChannel)
        }
      }
      completionHandler(channels)

    })
  }
}
```

This is how I reload the collection view after the json objects have been updated:

```
 var channelArray: [ChannelInfo] = []

      override func viewDidLoad() {

        channelArray = ChannelInfo.updateAllChannels(completionHandler: { _ in

        self.channelCollectionView.reloadData()
        })//Error happens here starting with 'channelArray'
    }
```

I get the feeling I may be missing a step, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Typically this message means you're assigning a function/closure to something that should be a class/struct type. Double check your code and option click your variables to ensure when you add anything to your array, it's of the type you expect. It may also help to clear your derived data and re run.

Comment: As another note, as far as guidelines for Swift syntax, try to be more robust in naming conventions, `let nm` should be `let networkManager` or something robust and contextually relevant. You shouldn't simplify anything that way. Just overall good coding habits and it follows the Swift API guidelines (don't abbreviate).

Comment: So were you thinking of telling us _which line_ gets this error?

Comment: Whoops, I updated the code with the error, it happens in the viewDidLoad where channalArray = ...

Comment: Okay, well, the mistake is very simple and easy to explain. What I can't explain is what you think you're doing. :( But I'll explain the error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, let's take this one step at a time. You are saying

```
ChannelInfo.updateAllChannels...
```

So let's look at how that `updateAllChannels` method is declared:

```
static func updateAllChannels(
    completionHandler:@escaping (_ channels: [ChannelInfo]) -> Void){
```

So this a static function that returns *no result*.

But what you are *actually* saying is:

```
channelArray = ChannelInfo.updateAllChannels...
```

But we have just established that `updateAllChannels` returns *no result*. So there is nothing there for you to assign to `channelArray`. The whole notion of assignment here makes no sense. And the compiler is telling you so. You can't have this assignment `channelArray =`. Delete that part.

---

I *think* (but don't quote me) that your larger problem is that you are ignoring the value returned to the completion handler. You have this:

```
ChannelInfo.updateAllChannels(completionHandler: { _ in
    self.channelCollectionView.reloadData()
})
```

See the `_ in` at the end of the first line? I think that's your whole issue. `updateAllChannels` is handing you back the `channels` as the parameter *and you are throwing them away*. Instead, I think you want something like this:

```
ChannelInfo.updateAllChannels(completionHandler: { channels in
    channelArray = channels
    self.channelCollectionView.reloadData()
})
```

Comment: I think I see what you mean.  But how can I call the function "updateAllChannels" so I can reload the collection view with the new json data?

Comment: That is what you _are_ doing, isn't it? You are calling `updateAllChannels` along with a completion handler that calls `reloadData`. So you _are_ reloading the collection view.

Comment: I am but the error : Cannot assign value of type '()' to type '[ChannelInfo]' is occurring

Comment: But I told you what to do about that. Delete `channelArray =`. You can't say that.

Comment: It looks like I did a poor job of explaining why I did the channelArray =..., I'm trying to update the local channelArray by calling the updateAllChannels function.  The local channelArray is connected to what is shown in the collection view, if it's not updated the collection view is blank.

Comment: But I told you how to fix that too.

Comment: essentially I'm trying to make the channelArray to be equal to the [ChannelInfo] the updateAllChannels returns in its completion handler

Comment: oh, I didn't see the 2nd part of your answer, I'll try that out

Comment: More than trying it, think about what I'm telling you in my answer.

Comment: That did it! Thanks for your help and patience!